# mobile device autoselect corresponding client cert

Tags: android, ios, iis, x509, client-certificates

havn't found anything about this, would like to know your thoughts..

we got IIS running with certificate authentication, but:
- mobile devices get a popup to select client certificate > hard to guess from serial
- every device reboot, had to select again > annoying

1. we got a mobile device registried with mdm, client certificate enrolled
2. client access gateway url, get requested to a popup
3. select popup
4. gateway authenticate based ob the selected client certificate

[ios cert popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpwIu.png)

How to get rid of the popup, are the any kind of solution server or client side to "autoselect" a client certificate, e.g. from subject

Thanks in advance
Matthias

Comment: Based on my understanding, desktop web browser won't pop up when there's only one certificate. Since this pop up operation is controlled by client side. Have you tried to leave only one client certificate? Because I haven't find anyway to control auto selection in IOS.

Comment: thanks for the input, good to know with one certificate, but the mobile device (ios&android) configured with several certificates (vpn, ssl tunnel, wifi, etc.)